# Application error: Deployment of react js project on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I follow the tutorial from https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f. Everything is working perfectly and I'm done configure my package.json by adding  new object named `engines` but when I open the app it show application error and I run this command `heroku logs --tail` and it shows error below.

```
2020-11-06T10:18:19.369209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-06T10:20:14.005978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-beyond-93095.herokuapp.com request_id=6563476d-6eb0-47ad-8c85-39d457e22a20 fwd="110.54.238.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
=immense-beyond-93095.herokuapp.com request_id=6597bf5d-2d7f-477f-a893-aef0cb946619 fwd="110.54.238.117" dyno= connect= s=immense-beyond-93095.herokuapp.com reqervice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "uncle-edge-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Uncle Edge Unli Wings",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.4",
    "node": "12.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "moment": "2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.5.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-slick": "0.26.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && gulp licenses",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "build-package-css": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss dist/material-kit-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.css --source-map true"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": []
  }
}
```

this is the site `https://immense-beyond-93095.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Did you add the react buildpack? It's missing in the description of your article but it is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding the react buildpack. thanks!